# how to get count of unread messages in a Kafka topic for a certain group

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I know, Kafka is meant to be dealt with like an infinite stream of events, and getting the remaining messages count isn't a built-in functionality. but I have to somehow ***monitor*** how my consumer processes are doing and if I'm providing enough resources for them.
overall scenario is basic Kafka usage, a couple of producers on different servers insert into a topic, consumers in `group_a` read messages, perform some AI stuff and insert into another topic for further processing.
rate of incoming messages is in no way constant or predictable, so I need to have a measure of checking if my consumers are lagging behind (let's say if `group_a` has more than 1000 *unread* messages in my input topic).

considering I have full control over Kafka setup, as well as consumer and producer code, what are my options here ?

- I assume reading the whole topic without any heavy processing and counting messages is neither clean nor efficient (?)
- if there was only a single pair of producer/consumer I could count the number of produced and consumed messages and calculate the remaining ones, but I'm running a multi-server setup and it's not quite feasible. is it possible to use the Kafka itself as a shared data store and keep count of all the produced and consumed messages?
- to avoid the ***XY problem*** is counting the number of unread messages the right way to know if my consumers are given "enough" resources?

***EDIT:
if you need to implement this in python yourself, I posted my solution as an answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73670700/9940814)***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka maintains metadata of the message offsets per partition consumed by each consumer. Partitioning enables you to have have multiple consumers for single topic.

Lag is the delta between consumer group offset and latest offset in the topic.

These metadatas are maintained by Kafka, and you do not need to maintain them in your app.

You can check consumer group offset and lag using for example [CLI tool](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#kafka-consumer-describe-group).

in the example below, foo group has consumed all messages from the topic "quickstart-events", so lag is 0. In this example there's just one partition and one consumer in the topic.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group foo                                                        

GROUP           TOPIC             PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                         HOST            CLIENT-ID
foo             quickstart-events 0          3               3               0               consumer-foo-1-0fbf8d40-732f-483d-91d3-9b6f686b5040 /127.0.0.1      consumer-foo-1
```

Same information is available also via the [AdminClient API](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html), see describe_consumer_groups.

If you need to automate reacting to the lag, it might be better to have separate monitoring process for the lag instead of trying to detect the lag inside the consumer processes. One tool for such approach is the [Kafka Lag Exporter](https://github.com/lightbend/kafka-lag-exporter). Benefit of this approach is that you can do alerts and dashboards using generic monitoring tools, but of course there's bit work required to setup the required infrastructure.

It's important to have sufficient number of partitions for each topic, since max. number of concurrent consumers for a topic is determined by the number of partitions.

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. it even has a  Kafka-python implementation :) thank you. and yes I'm monitoring in a separate process with its own dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who needs to do this in python, this is what I ended up implementing using `kafka-python` package.

```
from kafka.protocol.offset import OffsetRequest_v0, OffsetResetStrategy
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient


class KafkaMonitor:

    def __init__(self, host) -> None:
        self.host = host
        self.connected = False
        self.connect()

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.admin = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers = self.host)
            self.connected = True
            return True
        except:
            self.admin = None
            self.connected = False
            return False

    def get_stats(self, target_topic, target_group):
        stats = {"available":False, "has_data":False, "lag":{}}
        if (not self.connected) and (not self.connect()): return stats
        stats["available"] = True
        try:
            offsets = self.admin.list_consumer_group_offsets(group_id=target_group)
            for (topic, partition), (offset, metadata) in offsets.items():
                if topic==target_topic:
                    stats["lag"][partition] = {"offset":offset}
            if stats["lag"]:
                for broker in self.admin._client.cluster.brokers():
                    topic_partition_list = self.admin._client.cluster.partitions_for_broker(broker.nodeId)
                    if topic_partition_list is None: continue
                    partitions = [partition_i for topic_i, partition_i in topic_partition_list if topic_i==target_topic]
                    request = OffsetRequest_v0(replica_id=1, topics=[
                        (target_topic, [(partition_i, OffsetResetStrategy.LATEST, 1) for partition_i in partitions])])
                    future = self.admin._send_request_to_node(node_id=broker.nodeId, request=request)
                    self.admin._client.poll(future=future)
                    response = future.value
                    for topic, meta in response.topics:
                        if topic==target_topic:
                            for partition, erorr_code, end in meta:
                                stats["lag"][partition]["end"] = end[0]
                                stats["lag"][partition]["lag"] = stats["lag"][partition]["end"] - stats["lag"][partition]["offset"]
                stats["has_data"] = True
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e)
            self.connected = False
        return stats
```